# Render Style attribute directly in <div> - JSF

Tags: jsf, styles

I'm having an issue with JSF (a field I know few if any).

I need to render a "style='display: none'" inside a  based on the string an object property returns.

Code is:

```
 <div class='x' style='#{obj.styleprop}'>
```

- styleprop is defined in class obj with a getter and setter.
- styleprop may contain "display: block" or "display: none"

The div is always getting rendered this way:

```
 <div class='x' style=''>
```

Div must be always rendered.

I'm absolutely not sure what to do about...

Comment: for start place in your jsf page the following test / check `this is my style: ----- #{obj.styleprop}   ----- `  to see what value you got there in your bean , cause for some reason `styleprop` evaluates into empty string

Comment: Thanks for the advice, Daniel. Property is being rendering as expected. But not in Style attribute.

Comment: Which version of JSF are you using?

Comment: Richfaces 4.1. The div is inside a f:verbatim tag, which is iterated over a a4j:repeat block. Outside f:verbatim, attribute is correctly rendering. Inside, it shows empty string. I had to create another div outside f:verbatim and style is being shown as expected. Not the solution I like, but the one that works...